# date_range only specific days in every month, in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I was working with datetime dataset and got stuck here.
Trying to create a datetime column having only 23 days in every month from 2013-03-01 to 2017-06-01
the date column should be like.

```
Date:
2017-03-01
2017-03-02
...
2017-03-23
2017-04-01
2017-04-02
...
2017-04-22
2017-04-23
```

the ... between the column values says that they have values in between.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with [CustomBusinessDay](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html)

```
cf = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask="Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat", 
                                          holidays=[d for d in pd.date_range("01-jan-1990",periods=365*50, freq="D") 
                                                    if d.day>23])

pd.date_range("01-jan-2021", periods=60, freq=cf)
```

#### output

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04',
               '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08',
               '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12',
               '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-16',
               '2021-01-17', '2021-01-18', '2021-01-19', '2021-01-20',
               '2021-01-21', '2021-01-22', '2021-01-23', '2021-02-01',
               '2021-02-02', '2021-02-03', '2021-02-04', '2021-02-05',
               '2021-02-06', '2021-02-07', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-09',
               '2021-02-10', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-12', '2021-02-13',
               '2021-02-14', '2021-02-15', '2021-02-16', '2021-02-17',
               '2021-02-18', '2021-02-19', '2021-02-20', '2021-02-21',
               '2021-02-22', '2021-02-23', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-02',
               '2021-03-03', '2021-03-04', '2021-03-05', '2021-03-06',
               '2021-03-07', '2021-03-08', '2021-03-09', '2021-03-10',
               '2021-03-11', '2021-03-12', '2021-03-13', '2021-03-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```